# codigo funcional no se ejecuta en mi bot de telegram

Tags: javascript, nodejs, heroku, telegram

El problema es que este codigo:

```
const Jimp = require('Jimp');

var map = [["⬜","⬜","u","⬜","⬜","⬜"],["⬜","⬜","⬜","⬜","⬜","⬜"], 
           ["⬜","⬜","⬜","⬜","⬜","⬜"],["⬜","⬜","⬜","⬜","⬜","⬜"], 
           ["⬜","⬜","⬜","⬜","⬜","⬜"],["⬜","⬜","⬜","⬜","⬜","⬜"]];

var imageData = [
[ 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0x00FF00FF, 0xFF0000FF ],
[ 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0x0000FFFF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF0000FF ],
[ 0xFF0000FF, 0x00FF00FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0x0000FFFF ],
[ 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0x00FF00FF, 0xFF0000FF ],
[ 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0x0000FFFF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF0000FF ],
[ 0xFF0000FF, 0x00FF00FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0x0000FFFF ]
];

for (var i = 6 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (var o = 6 - 1; o >= 0; o--) {
        if(map[i][o]=="⬜"){
            imageData[i][o]=0xFFFFFFFF;
        }
        else{
            imageData[i][o]=0x000000FF;
        }
    }
}

var id=scaleArray(imageData,30);

let image = new Jimp(180, 180, function (err, image) {
if (err) throw err;

id.forEach((row, y) => {
   row.forEach((color, x) => {
     image.setPixelColor(color, x, y);
   });
});

image.write('test.png', (err) => {
   if (err) throw err;
   });
});

function scaleArray(src, factor) {

var srcWidth = src[0].length,
  srcHeight = src.length,
  dstWidth = srcWidth  * factor,
  dstHeight = srcHeight * factor;

 var dst = [];
 for (var col = 0; col < srcHeight; col++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < factor; i++) {
       var current_col = [];
       for (var row  = 0; row < srcWidth; row++) {
           for (var j = 0; j < factor; j++) {
               current_col.push(src[col][row]);
           }
       }
    dst.push(current_col);
  }
}
return dst;
}
```

Este codigo recoge lo que hay en el array map, y lo convierte en una imagen de 500x500, en este caso me devuelve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero una vez lo intento utilizar dentro de un comando de mi bot:

```
 bot.onText(/\/photo/, (msg)=> {
    makePNG();
    bot.sendPhoto(msg.chat.id, "test.png");
 });
```

usando la funcion o metiendolo directamente en el mensaje:

```
    function makePNG(){
    for (var i = 6 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (var o = 6 - 1; o >= 0; o--) {
            if(map[i][o]=="⬜"){
                imageData[i][o]=0xFFFFFFFF;
            }
            else{
                imageData[i][o]=0x000000FF;
            }
        }
    }
    var imgr=scaleArray(imageData,30);
    var image = new Jimp(180, 180, function (err, image) {
      if (err) throw err;

      imgr.forEach((row, y) => {
        row.forEach((color, x) => {
          image.setPixelColor(color, x, y);
        });
      });
      image.write('test.png', (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
      });
    });
}
```

Esto hace que no se envie la foto del bot, sin embargo, si ya tengo creada la imagen, y antepongo el bot.sendPhoto a la funcion, me envia esa foto, osea, que la ejecucion se detiene a la hora de converit mi array en una foto.

Les agradeceria mucho la ayuda.
pd: este es el error que devuelve, y no me aclara nada:

```
error: [polling_error] {}
```

Comment: Hola RGVylar, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Puede que esté sucediendo que llame a enviar la foto cuando aun no acabó el metodo de `makePNG()`. Deberias usar `promises` para asegurarte de que no es llamada hasta que la foto esté lista. Mira [ask] para más info en como mejorar la pregutna. Un saludo.

Comment: @lois6b Muchas gracias por la amabilidad, ahora mismo me pongo con ello a ver si se soluciona. Y perdon, deberia haberme leido todo antes de empezar con las preguntas, fallo mio. Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Como dijo @lois6b el problema era que no daba tiempo a terminar la imagen antes de que se ejecutara el envio:

```
    bot.onText(/\/photo/, (msg)=> {
    promise=new Promise(resolve => {
        for (var i = 6 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (var o = 6 - 1; o >= 0; o--) {
                if(map[i][o]=="⬜"){
                    imageData[i][o]=0xFFFFFFFF;
                }
                else{
                    imageData[i][o]=0x000000FF;
                }
            }
        }
        var imgr=scaleArray(imageData,30);
        var image = new Jimp(180, 180, function (err, image) {
          if (err) throw err;

          imgr.forEach((row, y) => {
            row.forEach((color, x) => {
              image.setPixelColor(color, x, y);
            });
          });
          image.write('test.png', (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
          });
        });
        resolve();
    }).then(_ => {
      bot.sendPhoto(msg.chat.id, "test.png");
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });JJ
});
```

No se si lo estoy haciendo bien, pero por ahora, el problema se ha solucionado.

Comment: me alegro que encontraras una solucion. (tienes "JJ" en la penultima linea ). Mira tambien [answer] para más info en como mejorar las respuestas. (muchos links hoy ehh? haha )